# Change Text on Status Strip Label inside a click event on Table Layout Panel moves Form to Selected Control

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have a very weird issue which I cannot manage to fix.

**The Problem**

Inside a Windows Form I have a StatusStrip and a tableLayoutPanel. That StatusStrip contains one label which will change its text depending on the row clicked. The tableLayoutPanel is set to autoScroll since the content is bigger than the size of my form.

Each row will have different controls. You can find buttons, labels, text boxes or checkboxes.

I'm able to select the row and change the text according to the selected row. The problem comes when I have scrolled down and then click on the table. For some reason, the Form will move to the last selected Control within the table.

For instance, If I have clicked inside a textbox, and I scroll down, where I cannot see the textbox, when I click on a table row. The form will automatically move to show the textbox.

It seems to me that for some reason, when I change the text it must repaint the whole table and then it moves to the last selected control.

**What Have I tried**

1. Move the table inside a panel.
2. Move the panel to another panel.
3. As for now, the panel is removed, doesn't seem to be necessary.
4. Originally I had 6 labels, removed them all to ensure it happens with just one.
5. If I don't change the text, but for instance, shows a message inside the Debug then the problem disappears, which for me it indicates that the problem resides inside the "change text" event.
6. ** EDITED **: If I change a label inside the table, the problem is gone. So it seems to be a combination with the table + the status label.
7. ** EDITED **: If I move the auto scroll to the form instead of the table. Then the problem is gone. But this is not what I want because then, my status bar won't be visible since it will be on the button and I need it to keep visible.
8. ** EDITED **: If I use a menu strip the problem is still there. If I move the status Stript. The problem is still there.
9. ** EDITED **: If I remove the panels and use a label inside the form. The problem persist.

**The Code**

I will keep code to a minimum and will add more if it is necessary.

This is where I update the toolStriptStatusLabel:

```
System::Void updateSelectedRow(int row) {       
    if (row == selectedRow)
        return;
    selectedRow = row;
    Command ^cmd = commandsList[row];
    commandToolStripStatusLabel->Text = cmd->name;
}
```

This is my click event:

```
System::Void tableLayoutPanel1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {              
    System::Drawing::Point ^point = GetRowColIndex(
        tableLayoutPanel1,
        tableLayoutPanel1->PointToClient(Cursor->Position           
        ));
    updateSelectedRow(point->Y);
}
```

This is where I find the Row I clicked:

```
System::Drawing::Point ^GetRowColIndex(TableLayoutPanel ^tlp, Point point) {
    if (point.X > tlp->Width || point.Y > tlp->Height)
        return nullptr;

    int w = tlp->Width;
    int h = tlp->Height;
    array<int> ^widths = tlp->GetColumnWidths();

    int i;
    for (i = widths->Length - 1; i >= 0 && point.X < w; i--)
        w -= widths[i];
    int col = i + 1;

    array<int> ^heights = tlp->GetRowHeights();
    for (i = heights->Length - 1; i >= 0 && point.Y < h; i--)
        h -= heights[i];

    int row = i + 1;

    return gcnew Point(col, row);

}
```

Comment: I forgot to add, I already have another StatusStrip in another form. It changes the text without problems, but it is not a click event, it uses a mousemove event. I think it could be related on how the tableLayout is generated or something. Maybe it repaints itself when something changes in the form.

Comment: I noticed there are two events being triggered: The Paint Event from the Table and a Layout event from the form. I tried to capture the actual AutoScroll Position before this happen and reset it during the Event. For some reason, that doesn't work at all. If I show the point before this happens, try to change it, and show it once again after the change, it shows the previous value. It is like this->tableLayoutPanel1->AutoScrollPosition = p; is just being ignored... this is getting weirder after every test :/

Comment: TableLayoutPanel is often ab/used to implement a grid control.  This rarely come to a good end.  It is only good at layout, it has none of the behavior of a grid.  So anything like "click a row" cannot work, only the controls inside the TLP can get the focus.  And only controls that are able to handle focus, so not Label.  A ScrollableControl automatically scrolls to ensure that the child control with the focus is visible, surely what you see happening.  Lots and lots of real grid controls out there, the one in the VS toolbox is DataGridView.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right, the problem with the DataGridView is that a column can only have one type of control, for instance, you create a button column or a text column, but I didn't find (I admit I didn't search so much) a way to have different controls in the same column, that is why I used the other layout. Anyway. I'm pretty sure (this is my assumption, I can be wrong) the problem is that each time you change a label, your form is repainted. When the form is repainted, the Table repaints itself to the last visited control. Anyway, using textboxes instead of labels seems to work for now.